# Mass Distribution Inside Sphere with Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, gravity

(Shell Theorem) If a mass is spherically symmetrically distributed within a spherical region, an observer measuring the gravitational pull from that spherical region would not know how the mass is distributed exactly. It could all be at the center, or all be at the edges, distributed evenly, etc.

Assuming it is all at the same temperature for these two examples, if 50% all the mass was at the edges, with the other 50% in the center, the mass on the edges would have a higher gravitational potential energy than mass at the center. With more energy, E=mc^2, it would have more mass and thus this region more gravitational pull than if it was all concentrated at the center.

Is my analysis correct? I understand the Shell Theorem is only really meant for classical mechanics.

Comment: If you wanted to calculate this properly, you would need general relativity, in which case the mass distribution wouldn't be described by a scalar field, but by the energy-momentum tensor $T$ (a symmetric 4-by-4 tensor with 10 independent components). For your example $T_{00}$ would contain the scalar matter density and $T_{11}$, $T_{22}$ and $T_{33}$ would contain the pressure distribution, which, of course, would be increasing towards the core. I can't tell you what happens if you model a realistic $T$ for a spherical shell vs. bulk, but I believe that the shell theorem might still apply.

Comment: Note that [Newton's shell theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem) generalizes to [GR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkhoff%27s_theorem_%28relativity%29).

Answer (score 0):

If you had a modular system of rods and connectors (like for making molecular models) then a certain number could be used to make a spherical shell of surface area $4\pi R^2$ that an observer far away would say has a mass M.

You could then rearrange the parts to make a thicker shell with a smaller surface area. If you kept the parts at the same temperature and if the stresses involved were negligible then you have two options.  Either the mass that an observer far away says you have will be smaller than M.  Or instead you could use more rods and connectors so that the observer far away says you have the same mass M.

In the later case this is what the theorem describes. You don't know if more material was used to make a more compact shell or whether less material was used to make a shell of larger surface area.

This lack of knowledge of which case holds is the actual theorem.